# Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to target a place on my webpage by using this code

```
<div id="mover" onclick="moveTo(".main", 3);">erer</div>
```

thats my button ^^

this is my function vv

```
this.moveTo = function(el5, page_index) {

if (typeof el5 == "string") el5 = document.querySelector(el5);

    var current = document.querySelector(settings.sectionContainer + ".active"),
        next = document.querySelector(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + (page_index) + "']");

    if(next) {
      var next_index = next.dataset.index;
        _removeClass(current, "active");
        _addClass(next, "active");
        _removeClass(document.querySelector(".onepage-pagination li a" + ".active"), "active");
        _addClass(document.querySelector(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + (page_index) + "']"), "active");

        body.className = body.className.replace(/\bviewing-page-\d.*?\b/g, '');
        _addClass(body, "viewing-page-"+ next_index);

        pos = ((page_index - 1) * 100) * -1;

        if (history.replaceState && settings.updateURL == true) {
            var href = window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf('#')) + "#" + (parseInt(page_index) - 1);
            history.pushState( {}, document.title, href );
        }
        _transformPage(el5, settings, pos, page_index, next);
    }
}
```

i KEEP getting this error, 'uncaught syntax error:unexpected token }'
and its highlighting this code below and i cant find anything wrong

```
<div id="mover" onclick="moveTo(".main", 3);">erer</div>
<div class="container" style="height:70px">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the double quote inside the function from

```
<div id="mover" onclick="moveTo(".main", 3);">erer</div>
```

To single quote

```
<div id="mover" onclick="moveTo('.main', 3);">erer</div>
```

Your double quotes inside the function conflict with the double quote which denotes the scope of `onclick` attribute.

**Suggestion**

Since double quotes are commonly used inside HTML, we ought to use single quotes for JavaScript *in the most cases* string so both don't conflict with each other.

Comment: what a no brainer!   now that is fixed im on to a new error in the chain::  'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null' is the warnign and it points to this code::  if (ele.className) {

Answer (score 1):

Change your `onclick` so the inner quotes are single quotation marks (rather than double quotation marks)

```
onclick="moveTo('.main', 3);"
```

Your second double quotation mark was closing the string so you basically had the following...

```
onclick="moveTo("  .main  ", 3);"
```

and the parser didn't know how to handle the `.main` in between your quotes.